# html tag to resize size of html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a tag I can wrap around a html table or body to re-size it without affecting the functionality of the content being re sized. Is the best way to do this to wrap the content in a html table and then re size the table itself ?

Comment: What is it that you want to resize? Why not just use CSS?

Comment: Can you clarify? You're asking to re-size something without affecting the contents which is impossible. What content are you resizing? What is the absolute smallest you can shrink the target?

Comment: If I am understanding this right, you want a wrapper around a table and be able to resize said wrapper without resizing the table? You could just make a <div> around the table and then fix the width and height of the table.

Comment: probably shouldn't wrap <body> in a tag..

Comment: @David Thomas I want to re size content within the body tag

Comment: @David Nguyen The content consists of various radio buttons and text fields. I realize the content size will be affected but as long as the form functionality is not affected thats ok. The absolute smallest is 30% of screen width * 30% of screen height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery.wrap()

```
$("#content").wrap("<table>")

    or with attribute

$("#content").wrap("<table id='wrapper'>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplistic case using CSS:

```
<body class="resize">
    Lorem ipsum..
</body>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
<style>
    .resize {
        font-size: NEW FONT SIZE;
        height: NEW HEIGHT;
        width: NEW WIDTH;
    }
</style>
```

Or dynamically with jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass('resize');
```